# Aligning div to the center of the page

Tags: css

I realize this question is repetitive on SO. But all those solutions and what I have always used to achieve it fails this time. I apologize for it.

My HTML Code so far:

```
<div class="arrow">
   <hr class="left">
   <img src="http://bit.ly/100X8XQ" height="10" width="10">
   <hr class="right">
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow{
margin:0 auto;
}

.left{
float: left;
width: 30%;
}

img{
float: left;
}

.right{
float: left;
width: 30%;    
}
```

I want to align the div "arrow" that contains all the hr's and img to the center of the page.

```
margin:0 auto;
```

This also doesn't help me in getting that. How can I get this done? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` will work if you wrap the above html in a parent `div` that has a width

Comment: arrow must be wrapped in a container with text-align: center. Also .arrow should have width - otherwise it will be 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `.arrow` div with some container that has `text-align: center;`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow">
    <hr class="left">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/100X8XQ" height="10" width="10">
    <hr class="right">
  <div>
</div>


.container {
    text-align: center;
}
.arrow {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.arrow {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
display: block;
margin: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: red;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

**EDIT**
First one should work now. Tested.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
.arrow{
    width: 50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Check an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4kk6wc39/